# Installing python package for a particular version

Tags: python, pip

In the `cmd` when I type `where pip` I get the following results

```
F:\python39\Scripts\pip.exe
F:\python38\Scripts\pip.exe
F:\miniconda_pf\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Now I would like to install a package, let's say in the python38 folder, how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

Comment: No. Most of the commands given in that old question are not working.  ```C:\Users\xxx>python3.8 -m pip install pandas
'python3.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- This question has been asked a thousand times. This is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60866591/11138259 -- On Windows there is also the `py` command: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line

Comment: `F:\python38\Scripts\pip.exe install` or `F:\python38\python.exe -m pip install`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using conda, so you can use conda activate [environment name] and use install pip modules.

Comment: There is conda but I also installed python 3.8 and 3.8.  For conda, I can do it easily but for python 3.8, I could not find a solution.

Comment: Then why do you use python 3.8? Is there any particular reason of using local? If not, I think you can just simply use conda!